# Sending arguments when focussing an element

Tags: javascript, dom

I am focussing an element in the DOM like so:

```
element.focus();
```

Presumably this is firing a focus event under the hood? Can I supply arguments with this by using a different syntax?

I have tried the following without success. I can use jQuery if need be:

```
$('.my-selector').trigger({
  type: "focus",
  options: 'argument1',
});
```

The handler is bound using angular `ng-focus`:

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="onFocus($event)"/>
```

The handler function:

```
function onFocus(evt) {
  // I want to be able to distinguish events via state I pass
}
```

Comment: "_Presumably this is firing a focus event under the hood?_": There are some more steps to do when `.focus()` is called on an element: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dom-focus

Comment: Sent the data where? How are you catching the event ?

Comment: It might be a little out of context, but why do you need to pass arguments to the focus event? If you want to execute a function when an element is focussed can you not define it in the called function itself?

Comment: In general you can use `$('selector').trigger('event',[{extra:'params'}])` and then catch it with `$('selector').on('event', function(e, extras){..}`. But `focus` does not work (*and it is a [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2342)*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I will accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery you can use

```
$('selector').trigger('event',[param1, param2,...])
```

and catch those with

```
$('selector').on('event', function(e, param1, param2, ..){..}
```

(*as mentioned in http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-event-extraParameters*)

---

Unfortunately this will not work with the `focus` event as documented in this bug report: [Extra parameters are not passed when triggering focus](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2342)

(***note:*** it works in 1.8.3 and below, as mentioned in a linked/relevant bug report: [focus event ignores additional data when triggered](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1741))

Answer (score 0):

If you check documentation for [HTML DOM focus()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp) it does not support parameters

But [jQuery focus()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focus.asp) does support `function` as a parameter that specifies which function to run when focus event is triggered